# PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}, null) error in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

I have an app that has  a list of cards and for cards, I saved texts in firebase database and images in firebase storage. I want to implement google-sign-in for my app. I added SHA1 and SHA256 and I followed steps in [this](https://github.com/tensor-programming/flutter_fb_google_auth_example) tutorial for implementing google sign-in. Now when I clicked for login I see it's not working (you can see in [image: gif] file). I'm trying many ways for 3 days and I couldn't solve it!
[here](https://gist.github.com/MeshkaniMohammad/7367151a3dd2a31969e7a57ff88f86a3) is all of my codes.
and here is my log:

```
W/ActivityThread( 7024): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@bb6d004
D/EGL_emulation( 7024): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7a85480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7a83750)
D/EGL_emulation( 7024): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7a85480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7a83750)
E/flutter ( 7024): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7024): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}, null)
E/flutter ( 7024): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:185:58)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:224:20)
E/flutter ( 7024): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:292:48)
E/flutter ( 7024): #5      FBApi.signInWithGoogle (package:firebase_example/Model/Api.dart:18:64)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #6      LoginPageState._loginUser (package:firebase_example/Ui/LoginPage.dart:19:29)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #7      LoginPageState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase_example/Ui/LoginPage.dart:81:42)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #8      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:503:14)
E/flutter ( 7024): #9      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:558:30)
E/flutter ( 7024): #10     GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:102:24)
E/flutter ( 7024): #11     TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:242:9)
E/flutter ( 7024): #12     TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:175:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #13     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:315:9)
E/flutter ( 7024): #14     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter ( 7024): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter ( 7024): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:143:19)
E/flutter ( 7024): #17     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:121:22)
E/flutter ( 7024): #18     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:101:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #19     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:64:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #20     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:48:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #21     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:142:13)
E/flutter ( 7024): #22     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:99:5)
W/ActivityThread( 7024): handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@53cfd59
I/firebaseexampl( 7024): WaitForGcToComplete blocked Background on None for 8.655ms
I/firebaseexampl( 7024): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
I/firebaseexampl( 7024): Background concurrent copying GC freed 18668(1149KB) AllocSpace objects, 12(624KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 3.574ms total 196.627ms
I/firebaseexampl( 7024): WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on ProfileSaver for 49.287ms
W/firebaseexampl( 7024): Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, linking)
D/EGL_emulation( 7024): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7a85480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7a83750)
E/flutter ( 7024): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 7024): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=DEVELOPER_ERROR, resolution=null}, null)
E/flutter ( 7024): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:551:7)
E/flutter ( 7024): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:185:58)
E/flutter ( 7024): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 7024): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall.<anonymous closure> (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:237:28)
E/flutter ( 7024): #4      _RootZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1374:54)
E/flutter ( 7024): #5      _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:153:18)
E/flutter ( 7024): #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:612:39)
E/flutter ( 7024): #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:668:37)
E/flutter ( 7024): #8      Future._addListener.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:351:9)
E/flutter ( 7024): #9      _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
E/flutter ( 7024): #10     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
D/EGL_emulation( 7024): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe7a85480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe7a83750)
```

Comment: Is this a debug or a release build?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it's debug

Answer (score 0):

Copy the ID of the client that is in your project https://console.developers.google.com.
[image]

Paste the ID to your resources String the Android project
[image]
Finally add .requestIdToken (getString (R.string.default_web_client_id))

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions
            .Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
```

I hope it has been helpfull :)